# Fetch more than one row in php

Tags: php, mysqli

Actually I want a output of more than one row and its giving me only one. This is my code and it returns only one row.  But when I run the same query SELECT DISTINCTROW metal, $fsym from metals ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 in phpmyadmin it gives me my desired output of 4 rows.

```
function readAnother()
{
    $fsym =    $_GET['fsym'];
    echo $fsym . '<br>';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCTROW metal, $fsym from metals ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$this->fsym);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->metal = $row['metal'];
    $this->price_eur = $row[$fsym];

}
```

Comment: have you inspected the output - such as `var_dump( $row );` within the function?

Comment: In var_dump its returning only one row.

Comment: When i did $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); i am getting all the four rows as my desired output but getting another error now

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [metal] => palladium [price_eur] => 756.21 ) [1] => Array ( [metal] => platinum [price_eur] => 675.59 ) [2] => Array ( [metal] => silver [price_eur] => 13.6 ) [3] => Array ( [metal] => gold [price_eur] => 100.38 ) ) 
Notice: Undefined index: metal in C:\xampp\htdocs\metalsapi\object.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined index: price_eur in C:\xampp\htdocs\metalsapi\object.php on line 54

Comment: Add the Updated code on question

Comment: It's better to fetch rows one by one like that: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }`

Comment: @DsRaj i did that i took the query n pasted it in phpmyadmin and it gave me the correct output of 4 rows . But in this php its not coming

Comment: Undefine index error because of these two line: $row['metal'];$row[$fsym]
as the value is inside the array index

Comment: how to solve this issue @DsRaj . Please help.

Comment: where you use this $this->metal and $this->price_eur? I mean what you want in this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion on comment:
Use [fetchall](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

You can try below code

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $this->metal = $row['metal']; // by this it will add the last 4th record metal value in the variable 
    $this->price_eur = $row[$fsym];
}
```

I will recommend that if you want to use all rows 'metal' then use the proper array

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $finalArray[] = ['metal' => $row['metal'], 'price_eur'=> $row[$fsym]]

}
print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo muchh this second one worked.. Thank you i learnt a new thing today. @DsRaj

Comment: Reload the page and check again because it didn't show here: [How to mark as answer](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+confirm+answer+in+stackoverflow&amp;oq=How+to+confirm+answer+in+stackoverflow&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57j0.10757j1j7&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I don't have a 15 reputation, may be that's y its not taking

Comment: I did it... Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use following function: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php
Like that:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->metal = $row['metal'];
    $this->price_eur = $row[$fsym];
}
```

If you want to use `fetchAll` then use it like that:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $this->metal = $row['metal'];
    $this->price_eur = $row[$fsym];
}
```

Comment: yea Its done thank you for this valueable help. @Nikita Leshchev

Comment: @PayalTripathy then mark my answer as "answer" pls :)